# How to call a variable from another class

Tags: ios, variables, gps

First off, do you guys know of any good tutorial sites or books to learn how to code for iOS6?

Now to the problem at hand, I have an AppDelegate class and a ViewController class.

I am using the AppDelegate class to find my current location and save it as an NSString.

I have a label in my ViewController class where I want to display my location.

In java I would usually just do something like this

```
label.text = AppDelegate.myLocationString;
```

But I am fairly new to objective c and I don't know how to do the equivalent. To be honest I'm not even sure if I am taking the correct approach for this language. Is there another way to approach this problem in objective c?

I've tried searching around for how to do it but I'm not even sure that I'm phrasing my searches correctly so I don't know if I'm searching in the right direction.

Any help that could be offered would be very much appreciated

My code as it is now:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h

@class BIDViewController;

@interface BIDAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) BIDViewController *viewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myPosition;

@end
```

LocationManager class from AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSDate *eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) < 15) {

        //if it is within the last 15 seconds, use it. Else do nothing.

        if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 35.0) {

            //location seems pretty accurate so we will use it

            NSLog(@"latitude: %+.6f, longitude: %+.6f\n", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
            NSLog(@"Horizontal accuracy: %f", newLocation.horizontalAccuracy);

            int latDegrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
            int lonDegrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

            double latDecimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - latDegrees);
            double lonDecimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - lonDegrees);

            int latMinutes = latDecimal * 60;
            int lonMinutes = lonDecimal * 60;

            double latSeconds = ((latDecimal * 3600) - (latMinutes * 60));
            double lonSeconds = ((lonDecimal * 3600) - (lonMinutes * 60));

            _myPosition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lat: %d, %d, %1.4f, Lon: %d, %d, %1.4f", latDegrees, latMinutes, latSeconds, lonDegrees, lonMinutes, lonSeconds];

        }
    }
}
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *positionLabel;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "BIDViewController.h"
#import "BIDAppDelegate.h"

@interface BIDViewController ()

@end

@implementation BIDViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //I have tried setting the label's text here but to no avail so far, I have been 
    //able to set it as "blah" with the following line:
    //
    //    positionLabel.text = @"blah";
    //
    //and I have tried things such as the following to populate the label with the 
    //myPosition variable: 
    //
    //    positionLabel.text = _myPosition;
    //            or
    //    positionLabel.text = AppDelegate._myPosition;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setPositionLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reference the App Delegate from your view controller, first import its definition (which you've ready done):

```
#import "BIDAppDelegate.h"
```

and then in code get the delegate:

```
BIDAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BIDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

and then get the location from the delegate:

```
CLLocation *location = appDelegate.locationManager.location;
```

and then call whatever method you like on the location object:

```
NSString *descr = location.description;
```

Or get the pre-calculated position with:

```
NSString *position = appDelegate.myPosition;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying: "used type 'BIDAppDelegate' where arithmetic or pointer type is required"

for this line BIDAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BIDAppDelegate)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: @Ian My initial edit missed off a `*`.  It should be `(BIDAppDelegate *)`.

Comment: also, thank you for your reply, once I read through your comment I realised that the way you are going about it makes much more sense

Comment: @Ian No problem. Also Marco Pace's answer is also worthy of note as he shows how to actually set the label text.

Comment: Yep that got it! :D thank you very much. I'm getting the hang of this language now but it is quite tricky!

Comment: I just realised that this will only get the location once. What would be the best way to keep the label continuously updating?

Or is there a way to make to locationManager "push" a new location every time it gets one?

Comment: would it be a case of overriding the locationmanager class in the viewcontroler?

Comment: @Ian Ask a new question about that; you will get a better response.  Search first though, as it's almost certainly already been asked...  **EDIT** No, that won't work ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In your ViewController

```
BIDAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BIDAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[positionLabel setText:appDelegate.myPosition];
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to call a variable from another class?

Assume you are in `ClassB`

```
ClassA *aObj=... ; //create an object of ClassA
aObj.propertyName=...;//set the property or ivar
NSString *string=aObj.propertyName;//retrieve it
```

---

> do you guys know of any good tutorial sites or books to learn how to
>   code for iOS6?

http://www.lynda.com/Apple-training-tutorials/106-0.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials